# Understanding a simple HelloWord.c program built with GCC

Tags: windows, gcc, x86, disassembly

I am trying to understand how I find the main() function in a trivial HelloWorld.c program I am looking at in both IDA Pro and Ollydbg.

I have built a simple C program (see below) using gcc (32-bit release using Dev-C++).  I have the EntryPoint from the PE Optional header as 0x14E0, which corresponds to IDA's 'start' label.

What I don't see is a direct route to 0x00401500, which I *think* is the main() function setting up the stack.

Is there an easy way to find the main() function for a simple c program like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf ("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

In IDA Pro I see:

```
.text:004014E0 start           proc near
.text:004014E0                 sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:004014E3                 mov     ds:dword_405034, 0
.text:004014ED                 call    sub_401EA0
.text:004014F2                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:004014F5                 jmp     sub_401180
.text:004014F5 start           endp
.text:004014F5
.text:004014F5 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:004014FA                 align 10h
.text:00401500
.text:00401500 ; ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦ S U B R O U T I N E ¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦
.text:00401500
.text:00401500 ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00401500
.text:00401500 sub_401500      proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_401180+25Dp
.text:00401500
.text:00401500 var_10          = dword ptr -10h
.text:00401500
.text:00401500                 push    ebp
.text:00401501                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:00401503                 and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
.text:00401506                 sub     esp, 10h        ; char *
.text:00401509                 call    sub_401E80
.text:0040150E                 mov     [esp+10h+var_10], offset aHelloWorld ; "Hello World!"
.text:00401515                 call    printf
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're specifically asking "how do I find the `main` symbol in a compiled program?

Comment: Hi - thanks for responding.  
Partly, yes.  I am aware the symbol may not be in the compiled code, so I am wondering how we find the actual location of where main would sit, which I am guessing is 0x00401500 in the above example.

I am having trouble finding any documentation what happens between the entry point and the main function in a PE file.